# Apache Beam in-memory storage

Tags: apache-beam

My use case is an un-bounded streaming pipeline processing data in fixed hourly windows. However, I need to know the data from the previous window(s). Is there a way to store the data in an ArrayList somewhere in-memory, or do I have to write it in a db somewhere?

I'm trying to avoid sliding windows because only a part of the processing requires this data from previous window and I wanted to avoid overlapping as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try using stateful DoFn's. However, note that state itself is per-key-per-window. See https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html and https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html.

Note that in Beam windows are in "event time" (rather than "processing time") - so when data can arrive out of order (which is nearly always the case in practice), the notion of "previous window" no longer makes sense, because data for an earlier window may arrive after data for a later window. And data for some windows may simply never arrive. You will probably need to reformulate your algorithm taking this into consideration. It will be helpful if you describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: Hey @jfkk, thanks for the guidance. I'm still very new at Apache Beam so it'll probably take me a while to grasp the concepts. But the new developments certainly look exciting and seem to lend promisingly to my use-case. I'm working on processing some iot data and as data comes in, I need to identify whether they should be in the same batch (to be tagged with the same identifier). However, there's no particular time limit to how long a batch can last, so as I process the data, I want to include some parameters to document where the processing was 'left off' in the previous window.